# Problem with path method for limits

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

I have to prove that this limit does not converge:

$$\lim\limits_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}\dfrac{x^2}{x+y}$$

I've already tried to approximate the limit with $y=mx$, and the result is that it should converge to $0$, but that is also the result when I try to approximate it with a curve, so I don't know what else to do.

I would also appreciate it so much if you could tell me if this statement is right:

$$\lim\limits_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}\dfrac{x^2}{|x|+|y|}=0$$

because
$$|\frac{x^2}{|x|+|y|}|<|x|$$
So $f→0$ as $x→0$.

Thank you so much, and please if you do not understand something, ask me, it's been a while since I write something in English. Thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

Hint: what happens when $y = -x$?

Comment: But can I do that? I mean, isn't it the "0/0" situation the one that I'm trying to avoid?

Comment: First of all, it's not $0/0$, it's $x/0$.  Second, only the one point $(0,0)$ has to be avoided.  In order for the limit to exist, your function would have to be defined for all $(x,y)$ near, but not equal to, $(0,0)$.